# Does Nisan's pseudo-random generator relativize?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-bounded, derandomization

Nisan proved in "Psuedorandom Generators for Space-Bounded Computation",
that there exists a pseudo-random generator which "fools" space-bounded computations.
Does this construction hold for every oracle (at least for non-adaptive queries) ?

Comment: I can't answer this question, yet I wanted to point to a related paper titled "Hardness vs. Randomness" (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(05)80043-1), which you may find useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on whether in your definition of the Oracle TM, the oracle query tape is also bounded to be of logarithmic size: if it is bounded then the PRG fools also L^A for any A too, if it is not bounded then A can contain the list of "pseudorandom strings" and thus L^A will not be fooled.

Comment: This is true for all pseudo-random generators, however, for example, NW generator does relativizies if we assume hardness against the oracle we want to fool. I  was wondering whether we can do something of this kind also for this generator.

Comment: Since this PRG is completely specified (ie not based on some other "hard function f"), it's not clear how to use the oracle in the relativized setting.